# setting textarea to label and not value with jqueryui's autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

So let's say I have a database of names and ID's corresponding to those names. I want a textarea (well `input type="text"`) to autocomplete based on the name but to also populate the the label and not the value in the textarea. The value, I figure, can be set via a hidden input field.

How might I do this in jquery?

Here's an example of what I mean (doesn't work - not sure why):

http://jsfiddle.net/mMa7d/

If that did work it'd populate the numbers and not the names in the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.map` to get the names,

```
var data = [{
    label: "John Doe",
    value: 6
}, {
    label: "Jane Doe",
    value: 7
}];
$(function () {
    $("#names").autocomplete({
        source: $.map(data, function (value, key) {
            return {
                value: value.label
            };
        })
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/X82aC/835/)

**Edit**

```
 $("#names").autocomplete({
     source: function (request, response) {
         $.getJSON("your url here", function (data) {
             response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                 return {
                     value: value.label
                 };
             }));
         });
     }
 });
```

Comment: What if source is a URL and not an array? And there's also the question of how to populate a hidden input field as well..

Comment: autocomplete uses ajax to get the names / values. If all I wanted to do was make it so the names show up in the textarea I could just return the names. But that's not what I want. I want the names to appear in the textarea but I also want the value to appear in a hidden input area. The form I'm submitting to needs the ID - not the name. But it makes life easier if the name can be auto predicted.

Comment: Awesome - thanks! I had to append request.term to the url to get to return names based on what's been entered but that's easy enough. Thanks!